# How to bind two functions to one button?

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a click counter for a game I'm making, however for some reason 2 buttons render instead of 1. I'm trying to make one single button have 2 main functions, that being move() and onClick(). But obviously, I'm not doing something right. (designed for internet explorer)

"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."
:(

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Pringle Clicker 1.0-->
<!--The DP (Depletion Bar) code was origionally from w3schools.com, however it has been heavily modified-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pringle Clicker v1.0</title>
    <style> html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    body {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: #9898ff;
        opacity: 0.8;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #4349c2, #4349c2 25px, #5e5eff 25px, #5e5eff );
        background-size: 50px 100%;
    }

    .PringleButton {
        background-color: #FFEA00; /* Pringle Color */
        border: 5px solid black;
        color: black; /* Text Color */
        padding: 86px 52px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 32px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        cursor: copy;
    }

    .PringleButton:hover {background-color: rgba(236, 236, 57, 0.667)}

    .PringleButton:active {
        background-color: rgba(236, 236, 57, 0.667);
        transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    }

    .DPbar {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 200px;
        left: 725px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        background-color: seagreen;
        border-radius: 25%;
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<!--button and depletion bar functionality-->

<!--TO DO: 1: Make DP bar length shorter + center it (DONE 1/2)
           2: DP bar total percentage = 100% (DONE...kinda...)
           3: Tweak depletion speed (DONE)
           4: DP bar does not push pringle button (DONE)
           5: Clicking multiple times does not clone the DP bar (DONE)-->

<div id="DPbar" class="DPbar" style="width:0%">0%</div> <!-- Starting percentage of depletion bar-->
<br>
<button class="PringleButton" onclick="move()">Pringle!</button>
<button class="PringleButton" onClick="onClick()">Pringle!</button>

<script>
    var clicks = 0;
    var id = undefined; // --> MOVED ID OUTSIDE
    function move() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("DPbar");
        var width = 0; // Starting percentage 
        if (id) { // --> CLEAR ID IF EXISTS
            clearInterval(id);
        }
        function frame() {
            if (width >= 15) { // Length of depletion bar (ending percentage)
                clearInterval(id);
                alert("You Lose, reload (Ctrl + R) the page to play again!"); // Message displays after hitting 100% (or whatever is the final percentage)
            } else {
                width++;
                elem.style.width = width + '%'; // Speed of depletion bar also (idk?)
                elem.innerHTML = width * 6.7 + '%'; // Multiplier of percentage
            }
        }
        id = setInterval(frame, 75); // Speed of depletion bar
    }

    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };


    
</script>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Pringle Clicker 1.0-->
<!--The DP (Depletion Bar) code was origionally from w3schools.com, however it has been heavily modified-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pringle Clicker v1.0</title>
    <style> html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    body {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: #9898ff;
        opacity: 0.8;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #4349c2, #4349c2 25px, #5e5eff 25px, #5e5eff );
        background-size: 50px 100%;
    }

    .PringleButton {
        background-color: #FFEA00; /* Pringle Color */
        border: 5px solid black;
        color: black; /* Text Color */
        padding: 86px 52px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 32px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        cursor: copy;
    }

    .PringleButton:hover {background-color: rgba(236, 236, 57, 0.667)}

    .PringleButton:active {
        background-color: rgba(236, 236, 57, 0.667);
        transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
    }

    .DPbar {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 200px;
        left: 725px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        background-color: seagreen;
        border-radius: 25%;
        cursor: not-allowed;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<!--button and depletion bar functionality-->

<!--TO DO: 1: Make DP bar length shorter + center it (DONE 1/2)
           2: DP bar total percentage = 100% (DONE...kinda...)
           3: Tweak depletion speed (DONE)
           4: DP bar does not push pringle button (DONE)
           5: Clicking multiple times does not clone the DP bar (DONE)-->

<div id="DPbar" class="DPbar" style="width:0%">0%</div> <!-- Starting percentage of depletion bar-->
<br>
<button class="PringleButton" onclick="doBoth()">Pringle!</button>

<script>
    var clicks = 0;
    var id = undefined; // --> MOVED ID OUTSIDE
    function move() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("DPbar");
        var width = 0; // Starting percentage 
        if (id) { // --> CLEAR ID IF EXISTS
            clearInterval(id);
        }
        function frame() {
            if (width >= 15) { // Length of depletion bar (ending percentage)
                clearInterval(id);
                alert("You Lose, reload (Ctrl + R) the page to play again!"); // Message displays after hitting 100% (or whatever is the final percentage)
            } else {
                width++;
                elem.style.width = width + '%'; // Speed of depletion bar also (idk?)
                elem.innerHTML = width * 6.7 + '%'; // Multiplier of percentage
            }
        }
        id = setInterval(frame, 75); // Speed of depletion bar
    }

    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    
        function doBoth() {
        onClick();
        move();
    };


    
</script>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can have a root function that calls your other 2 functions. This results in one button calling both your function (one after the other)

Answer (score 0):

Just call 2 different functions with `onclick(call1(); call2())`. You don't have to write everything in one function.

```js
function clickMe() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}

function andMe() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " AND ME!";
}
```

```css
span {
  margin: 3rem;
  background: #fdc23e;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<span onclick="clickMe(); andMe()">Click me.</span>

<p id="demo">Not clicked</p>
```

Comment: Same logical code as accepted

Comment: Not quite. So sorry but I don't see it that way. If he packs everything in one method, it tends to have disadvantages, later when refactoring, etc. and when using it later, you have to search more where you use what. In a small project maybe not dramatic but you should still have structure.